# Admin menu items go nowhere

Tags: magento2, admin, url, adminmenu

I had trouble getting CSS to load, but go that fixed. However, now the admin meu items go nowhere and there are no icons. There were when I first fixed the CSS isue, but now there are just squares where the icons would be. That's minor compared to not being able to navigate anywhere. All menu links look like this:  http://rockeroffroad.com/shop/admin_bark001/admin/dashboard/index/key/e42e54314d31101d63366745ad79b35d8f7b8fd8eee3dad24486a40b39da22b1/#

Btw, should that URL be so crazy long?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which version you are using

Comment: Magento ver 2.0.2

Comment: css and js not applying right

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: front end also same or what

Comment: No, front end navigation and images OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Before that take Backup**

1. Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder
2. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**Note**: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: All that did was break my CSS again. Both front and back. And maybe I don't understand the instructions for the di.xml. It says find that line and "replace to." What does "replace to" mean? I changed the sord "Symlink" to "Copy." Is that right?

Comment: Is there anywhere else to get support for this thing? This really shouldn't be that hard, should it? This is why I hate ecommerce. Not a one of them ever seems to work. Anyway, I guess if that's all you got I'm stuck, because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you follow that link. It's working example. try to clear cache and session

Comment: I followed the link. I did what is said to do, with the exception of the "replace to" instruction. I just deleted that line in the di.xml, as there was one that said"/Copy" right underneath it. And I do not understand "replace to." It makes no sense.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean but i tried many times it works fines

Comment: I apologize. I'm not trying to be obtuse. The instructions say to find the path “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” and replace to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy Here is what I see in the di.xml file: <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            </argument>

Comment: Am I just to change the word "Symlink" to "Copy?" If so, it doesn't work. Am I to delete that line? If so, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry i don't have files i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from magento root

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

For Magento 2.1.x and earlery

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Use -f for force deploy on 2.2.x or late

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```